# problem when doing heroku rake db:migrate to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

when i do heroku rake db:migrate i get an error cant require jcode, i solved this problem in my localhost:3000 with the solution to overide this code:

require 'jcode'

to this:

if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'

to the gem contacts source and its worked in the localhost:3000 but when i pushed the app to heroku, heroku reinstalled all the gems and the problem backed. so i need to override again the code in /app/.bundle/gems/.... but when i do cd app, cd .bundle or cd ~/.bundle, i get canot find .bundle dir..

and in the heroku logs its looks like the .bundle dir exsitis

what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a ruby version issue obviously!

```
require 'jcode' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9' #require 'jcode'
```

Just add that.

[image]

Sorry for not reading. You need to unpack your gem and change it in that directory. I posted that picture which doesn't totally correlate with the exact code you need. But again this is the concept. Let me know if you have issues with this and I can write the exact code.

Comment: i know that!!! i wrote this in the comment i cant accses the .bundle dir!!! this is the problam!

Comment: when i do: rake gems:unpack GEM=gdata
i get: Don't know how to build task 'gems:unpack'
what to do? and what i need to write in replace to the VERSION? + i need to change in the vendoer the code again? and then change the gemfile and uplode it to heroku and all will be good?

Comment: Google your rails version number and 'vendorize gems'.

Answer (score 0):

try switching stacks at heroku

heroku stack:migrate bamboo-ree-1.8.7

Comment: !   Internal server error
and when i do heroku rake db:migrate i get: rake aborted!
no such file to load -- hpricot

Comment: switching from bamboo-mri-1.92 to bamboo-1.8.7 solved me the problem http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bamboo#migrating_from_aspen_to_bamboo